# Efficient Storage of rows with large fields in Azure

Tags: sql-server, azure, bigdata, azure-storage, azure-cosmosdb

Currently putting together a base POC of architecture for an application that will be storing large amounts of records and each record will have one field that contains a few thousand characters.

e.g. 
     TableID int
     Field1 nvarchar(50)
     Field2 nvarchar(50)
     Field2 nvarchar(MAX)

This is all being hosted in Azure. We have one webjob that does the work to obtain the data and populate it into the data store and then another webjob comes through periodically and processes the data.

Currently the data is just stored in an Azure SQL Database. I'm just worried once the record count turns into the many millions it's going to be incredibly inefficient to store/process/retrieve the data this way.

Advice required on the best way to store this in Azure. Wanted to start trying the fact that we keep the rows in Azure SQL but the large field's data is pushed into another repository (e.g. Data lake, DocumentDB) and has a reference back to the SQL record therefore the SQL calls are still lean and big data is stored somewhere else. Is this a clean manor of doing it or am I totally missing something?

Comment: Build a fully normalized data model to eliminate redundancy, and let the RBMS do its thing. To be **Big Data** these days a data store must be multiple terabytes.

Comment: You could possibly look at storing large data in blob storage as well. Each blob in blob storage can be up to 200GB.

Comment: The answer to this depends highly on the specific scenario. What is the data to be stored? Is it fairly heterogeneous? What does your workload look like? How is the data queried? What are your estimates in regards to read throughput, write throughput, amount of storage? Generally speaking, normalizing optimizes for write-heavy use-cases. Depending on scale - partitioning, materializing views, caching, etc. could all come in to play. In which case, using more specialized storage products will become highly beneficial.

Comment: Comments above are good. Not much to add, but it sounds like you want to explore blob fields because you are already using Azure SQL.DocumentDB is not any better at storing large values but it does have convenient support for attachments which would provide similar functionality to blobs on Azure SQL. High write rate -> SQL. A lot of data but low-mid read rate -> SQL. Very high read rate, partitionable data (e.g. multi-tenant, etc.) -> DocumentDB. Highly relational data -> SQL. ACID transactions -> SQL although DocumentDB's stored procedures provide ACID transaction support.

Comment: There's really no right answer to this, just opinions. We know nothing about the app, the query needs, anything. We can guess all day, suggest any type of database type, but it really doesn't matter, as it's all just opinions on a very broad question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure Table Storage can help with this solution - it is a NoSQL KeyValue store. Each entity can be up to 1MB in size. You could also use individual blobs as well. There is a design guide that includes a full description of how to design Table Storage solutions for scale - including patterns for using Table Storage along with other repositories see [Table Design Guide](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-table-design-guide/)
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-table-design-guide/